# Replace with regExp in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex

I have a problem with replace like this:

I have an array test :

```
test: Object
    boolean: "true"
    integer: "0"
    values|+|0: "option_1"
    values|+|1: "option_2"
```

and then i do parse like this:

```
for(var data in test){
   for(var input in test[data]){
   var input_aux = input.split('|+|');
   if(input != ''){
      $('table#'+table_id+' tbody td.'+input_aux[0]+' small').each(function(){ 
       var text_highlighted = $(this).text().replace(new RegExp('(' + test[table][input] + ')', 'gi'), '<b>$1<\/b>');
      $(this).html(text_highlighted);
    }}}
```

what i'm trying to accomplish is to match the data from the array like `option_1` that is in that table exactly `option_1` and change the html of it to `<b>option_1</b>`.

And it's working fine my problem is like when i have the same key but different value like in the example above, it will highlight only `option_2` and can't understand why, any idea?

Comment: you may have to replace `test[table][data]` by `test[data][input]` ?

Comment: @stribizhev, please go in details, just to mention it's working fine for integer and any other single keys, thanks!

Comment: Do you mean my hint was enough to solve the issue? Changing replacement string from `<b>$1<\/b>` to `<b>$1</b>`?

Comment: Are the values in the same element?

Comment: @epascarello no , they are in different td > small but the td's are with the same id like `td[class="values"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the fact you are doing replacements even if there is no match. So you are reading the text() of all the elements and replacing it with that text. So you wipe out all of the existing html.

So check to see if there is a match before you do the replacement.

```
var re = new RegExp('(' + test[table][input] + ')', 'gi');
var txt = $(this).text();
if (txt.match(re)) {
    var text_highlighted = txt.replace(re, '<b>$1<\/b>');
    $(this).html(text_highlighted);
}
```

other option would be to use [contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).

Comment: i'm reading only the `$('table#'+table_id+' tbody td.'+input_aux[0]+' small')`, so just the td's that have class included in the key of the array, is that an issue? i'm not reading all the table

Comment: This is your problem.

Comment: can you please give me more details, i really don't get my problem in the approach, sorry

Comment: You replace every element you loop through with the text(). The text() removes all the html in that element so you blow away the previous match!

Comment: @ epascarello --- Amazing answer, i wasn't really sure that somebody will understand what i wrote in the question, but you got the issue and save the situation, Thanks man! worked like a charm.

Comment: the code breaks if the string has special chars like the text '$$$aaa' , why ? the exact code that is not matching is `txt.replace(re, '<b>$1<\/b>'); `

Comment: This really should be a different question, but what is the regular expression?

Comment: ok, i fixed it anyway thank you but the answer above dose'n treat string like `$%aa`